# possible to print or check how many db connection request is open and if closed? django

Tags: python, django, database, database-connection, mariadb

Recently I am having errors of too much request that the host ip is blocked that I have to `flush hosts` in order for the connection to work again, I event went to `mariadb configuration` to change the `max_connetions, max_connect_errors` as I found in other forums but this error still happens sometimes even though not as often anymore.

I just want to double check and see if there's any part of my code that somehow the connection got opened but didn't close because there aren't that much people using the request (as I know of) when the error happens.

Is there a way in `django` or somewhere I can print out / see how many connections requests are opened and if they are closed after requests are done or something like that?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: There are several things in `GLOBAL STATUS`.  For further discussion, provide the things mentioned [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning)

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import connections


print(connections.all())
```

Comment: I got something like this, `[<django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fce0afba438>]
`.